# TextView hides last word that my be patially visible

Tags: android, textview, partial, visible, words

For example we have combination of 2 words: "Firstword secondword".
Textview have 1 line and it's width not big, so first word is visible, second to long to fit in rest space and it no visible: [Firstword______]
How to achieve partial visibility of second word?
Like this [Firstword secon] or [Firstword seco...](with ellipsize). Is it possible?
I've seen in some topics that what I want is default behaviour when use ellipsize, but not in my case.

Edit: android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1" work only in xml layout preview, but not work in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

This xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Helloooooooooooooooooooooo Wooooooooooooooooooooooooorld!"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Helloooooooooooooooooooooo Wooooooooooooooooooooooooorld!"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Helloooooooooooooooooooooo Wooooooooooooooooooooooooorld!"
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

render in design preview like
[image]

OK, all ellipsizes work here. 
But on real device it look like
[image]

android:singleLine="true" is only worked, in spite of it deprecated.
Tested on 3 devices.

Answer (score 1):

Add these in your TextView

**android:ellipsize="end"**
**android:maxLines="1"**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myTextView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's work in xml layout preview. 
But isn't work in runtime. Showing [Firstword..._____]
Is it may be because I use custom TextView with own ttf typeface?

Comment: textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);

Comment: textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END) not work too.
Even with default TextView.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you want set to textView programmatically this:

```
textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```